# Date.now() returning wrong format

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, time

I'm using express in nodejs for my backend and react for my frontend.

In the backend, I use Date.now() then add toLocaleDateString() to make it format as 12/25/2021.
For some reason, Date.now() is behaving oddly when I insert into MongoDB.

A simple "new Date()" is returning as "2021-12-20T05:01:48.055Z", and
Date.now() is returning the exact same thing... why is this happening? It never happened before.

When I type Date.now() in my web browser console, it returns the right thing.

Here's my code:

```
export const postSnippet = async function (req, res) {
    // Create new snippet
    let snippet = new Snippet({
        title: req.body.title,
        code: req.body.code,
        creator: req.body.creator,
        createdDate: Date.now(),
        updatedDate: Date.now(),
        collections: req.body.collections,
    });
    try {
        // Save snippet to database
        await snippet.save();
        return res.status(201).json({ message: "Snippet created", snippet });
    } catch (error) {
        // Error handling
        return res.status(500).json({
            message: "Failure creating snippet.",
            error: error.message,
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: _""The static Date.now() method returns the number of milliseconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC._ - is the definition. What is it you want to store in the `createdDate` field?

Comment: I want it to return something like '1639979481806', instead of '2021-12-20T05:43:39.278Z'. Later when I want to display the date, I will use myDate.toLocaleDateString() to make it display something like 1/1/2021

Comment: You can use `const created = new Date(snippet.createdDate)` to convert the timestamp back into an object. Then you can call `created.toLocalDateString()`

Comment: That works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Cameron, I found the solution.

Inside render() of Snippet.js, I added this up top, before return.

```
let newUpdatedDate = new Date(this.props.updatedDate);
let updatedDate = newUpdatedDate.toLocaleDateString();
```

Then adding to DIV

```
<div className="snippet-date">
    Last updated {updatedDate}
</div>
```

**Thanks for the support**

Thank you guys so much! I'm new to JavaScript but so far I am loving it. Stackoverflow has been an amazing website to get help. I'm learning so much. I believe this will open me up to a variety of new clients. Before this, all I knew was HTML/CSS with PHP/MySQL for backend/database. I used to love PHP religiously but now my favorite is Nodejs, and that's because you can learn and build literally ANYTHING you put your mind to